# Projections are open maps. Why might I be wrong?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

I got this problem from Munkres, my idea is similar, but comparing to the actual solution, I missed at least 4 steps.

> Prove that the projection maps $\pi_1 : X \times Y \to X$ and $\pi_2 : X \times Y \to Y$ are both open maps.

Here is my solution

> Let $U_1 \times U_2 \subset X \times Y$ be open in $X \times Y$, meaning $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open in $X$ and $Y$ respectively that is $U_1 \in \tau_X$ and $U_2 \in \tau_Y$. Now by the definition of $\pi_1$, we have $$\pi_1(U_1 \times U_2) = U_1 \in \tau_X$$ so the image is also open. The proof for $\pi_2$ is similar.

Now the solution in [page 4](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~m54x12/m54hwsolns2.pdf) of the pdf includes all these union and basis things. The only major thing I noticed is that I didn't consider either $U_1$ or $U_2$ to be empty, but I am not sure how meaningful it is to project on empty sets because the projection is still empty and that is clearly open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main issue with your solution is that you consider only those open sets in the product topology that are of the form $U_1\times U_2$ for some $U_1$ and $U_2$ open in $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Sure, sets of this form are open in the product topology, but there are many more open sets that cannot be expressed as simple products.

In particular, $V\subseteq X\times Y$ is open in the product topology if and only if there exist collections of open sets $\{U_1^{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ in $X$ and $\{U_2^{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ in $Y$, where $A$ is a non-empty index set, such that $$V=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_1^{\alpha}\times U_2^{\alpha}.$$

As for the issue with empty sets, if either $U_1$ or $U_2$ is empty, then $U_1\times U_2$ is empty and the image of the empty set is vacuously empty.

Comment: I am still confused, what is the introduction of the collections of open sets and unions for??

Comment: @sidht Be careful: the product topology on $X\times Y$ is _not_ $\{U_1\times U_2\,|\,U_1\in\tau_X,U_2\in\tau_Y\}$, but the collection of _all unions_ of sets of this form! This comes from the very definition of the product topology.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571689/open-sets-in-product-topology) is a nice example of why sheer products are not enough and why unions thereof are needed.

Comment: @triple_sec, what if we change the topology to open rectangles instead of open balls? Then it would work.

Comment: @sidht I'm afraid it wouldn't work, either. The union of two rectangles need not be a rectangle, but a topology should be closed under unions, by definition. I believe it would be very helpful for you to consult the definition of the product topology. It's §15 in Munkres (pp. 86–88).

Comment: Actually, I think this should be fine - unless I'm mistaken, you can check that $f : X\to Y$ is open by checking on a basis, which is what sidht is doing.

Comment: @triple_sec, you are right, that was hasty of me. Union of two disjoint rectangles is not a rectangle.

Comment: @Stahl You're right; the image mapping does happen to commute with unions (but not, in general, with intersections and complements, unlike the inverse image). I did feel, however, some confusion about realizing that the product topology is more than just the collection of products of open sets. Ultimately, what sidht did is indeed sufficient to see the openness of the projection maps, but explicit reference ought to be made how the result for the topological basis implies the result for the whole topology, as you mentioned. You might want to point this out in the form of an answer.

Comment: @triple_sec, thanks you did raised a point I was not aware of.

Comment: Both answers have been very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @sidht My pleasure, it was an interesting problem.

Answer (score 3):

As I noted in the comments of triple_sec's answer, what you did *is* in fact sufficient to prove that projections are open mappings. The reason your proof is enough is that a basis for the product topology on $X\times Y$ is given by sets of the form $U_1\times U_2$, with $U_1\subseteq X$ open and $U_2\subseteq Y$ open. In general, it is true that $f(A\cup B) = f(A)\cup f(B)$, so it is sufficient to check openness of a map $f : X\to Y$ on a basis for $X$ (i.e., check that any basis open has open image in $Y$ under $f$), the same way that it is sufficient to check continuity of $f$ on a basis of $Y$ (check that any basis open in $Y$ has open preimage in $X$). Of course, if you are proving statements like "a projection map is open," you will probably be expected to say why it's OK that you only check openness on a basis.

However, one does need to be careful, as a basis $\beta$ for a topology $\tau$ on $X$ is not the whole story: a general open set in $\tau$ is some union of basis opens, but not necessarily an element of $\beta$ itself! Although there are a number of properties that can be checked on a basis, there are also properties that cannot be checked on a basis, so one must realize the difference between $\beta$ and $\tau$ when examining a space $X$.

Comment: Thanks, but what did you mean in the 2nd paragraph when you say "is some union of the basis, but not necessarily an element of the basis itself!". Doesn't this contradict basis being closed under union?

Comment: @sidht I don't know of any definition of basis that requires it to be closed under unions. In fact, this is kind of the point of a basis: it is essentially a set of "simple" open sets such that any open set in the topology is a union of such simple opens (opens in the basis). It is the topology itself that needs to be closed under unions.

Comment: A collection of subsets of $X$, $\mathscr B$, is a (topological) **basis** if $\mathscr B\subseteq\mathscr\tau$ and every non-empty member of $\tau$ can be expressed as a union of sets in $\mathscr B$. Note that a basis $\mathscr B$ need not be closed under unions, as opposed to a topology $\tau$, which, of course, is closed under unions. It is possible that a base is much smaller than the topology it defines. Indeed, there exist topologies with uncountably many sets, yet having a countable basis. These topological spaces are called _second countable_. E.g., $\mathbb R^n$ is second countable.

Comment: @Stahl, you are correct. My mistake, I was thinking about something else (not the topology).

Comment: Also, I have to confess that I was not aware that not every open set can be decomposed into the cross product as triple_sec has indicated. This proof of mine is more of an accident from a transition of Rudin's analysis to this.

Comment: So just to clarify, basically I used $$f(W) = f(\cup_{i \in I} U_i \times V_i) = \cup_{i \in I} f(U_i \times V_i)$$ without stating that (1) finite/arbitrary union of open sets preserves openness (2) elements in the topology is union of elements in base, so that $U_1 = \cup_{\alpha} U_1^\alpha$ in the notation triple_sec used?

Comment: Your first formula is correct. I.e., if $X$ is an arbitrary space, $I$ is a nonempty index set, $U_i\subseteq X$ for all $i\in I$, and $f:X\to Y$ is a function, then $f(\cup_{i\in I}U_i)=\cup_{i\in I}f(U_i)$. Proof: if $y\in f(\cup_{i\in I}U_i)$, then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in\cup_{i\in I}U_i$, i.e., $\exists j\in I$ such that $x\in U_j$, so $y=f(x)\in f(U_j)\subseteq f(\cup_{i\in I}U_i)$. The other direction is similarly easy. Exercise: show that this formula does _not_ hold for intersections or complements, in general.

Comment: As for $U_1=\cup_{\alpha}U_1^{\alpha}$, be careful, for in general, it is _not_ true that $(\cup_{\alpha\in A}U_1^{\alpha})\times(\cup_{\alpha\in A}U_2^{\alpha})=\cup_{\alpha\in A}U_1^{\alpha}\times U_2^{\alpha}$. Check why it fails for $U_1^{\alpha}=U_2^{\alpha}=[1,3]$ and $U_1^{\beta}=U_2^{\beta}=[2,4]$.

Comment: That is, if $V$ is open in the product topology, then it can be expressed as $V=\cup_{\alpha\in A}U_1^{\alpha}\times U_2^{\alpha}$ (as argued before), but, defining $U_1\equiv \cup_{\alpha\in A}U_1^{\alpha}$ and $U_2\equiv \cup_{\alpha\in A}U_2^{\alpha}$, it is _not_ necessarily true that $V=U_1\times U_2$! Again, not every open set in the product topology can be expressed as a simple product of open sets.

Comment: Both answers have been very helpful, thank you.